auto click follow with accessibility
I want to click follow on the tiktok application using Accessibility with kotlin. But when using uiautomator I see that the follow button only has a text view with id com.ss.android.ugc.trill:id/cqm but the clickable attribute is false and the element The parent is a linearlayout without an id but the clickable property is true. How can I autoclick in this case? Thank you  .this is image on iuautomatorviewer .enter image description here
I hope you will give me an example code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
